# Class instance in the heap

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, classloader

I try to create a simple JPA application based on spring framework and Eclipselink JPA.

First of all initialize an EntityManagerBean:

```
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaDialect(new EclipseLinkJpaDialect());

    EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform");

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.egzi.diplom.model");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new SimpleLoadTimeWeaver());

    //to update existing table (alter table)+
    Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
    additionalProperties.setProperty("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "create-or-extend-tables");
    additionalProperties.setProperty("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode","database");

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```

And in a DAO class a try to persist some entity:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void createTODO() {
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    todo.setSummary("a");
    todo.setDescription("b");


    entityManager.persist(todo);
}
```

And entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Todo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String summary;
    private String description;

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Todo [summary=" + summary + ", description=" + description
                + "]";
    }

}
```

but when i run such code i have an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: Todo [summary=a, description=b] is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:262)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.egzi.diplom.spring.GeneratorImpl.createTODO(GeneratorImpl.java:59)
```

and when i look into a eclipselink sources i find HashMap with Class as a key:

org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstactSession.getDescriptor(Class):

```
descriptor = this.descriptors.get(theClass);
```

When i started to debug my code i find that descriptors map already have a key of Todo.class. And i find that identityHash of class in HashMap and Todo.class is a different. I start my code from Inteliji IDEA.

What's wrong in my example?

**UPDATE:**
find that classes in descriptors HashMap have a link on org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleInstrumentableClassLoader@14bb2297
but my Todo object have another one:
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@58644d46

Answer (score 0):

Try to add getter and setter for field ID too!

Comment: still have the same exception

Comment: hm, try to add @Table(name="yourName") after @entity!

Comment: i already try it. please note my last update in the main section. It looks like problem with classloaders...

Answer (score 0):

Fix exception by setting another LoadTimeWeaver - InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver and exception is gone